# How to use fopen_s when I need to ask for a filepath?

Tags: c, security-warning

I used to make fopen *safer* with this code

```
fin = fopen(ifp, "r");
fout = fopen(ofp, "w");
if ((fin == NULL)||(fout == NULL))
    printf ("Error opening files");
else {} //action
```

Now I moved to Microsoft Visual Studio 2013. It asks me to use fopen_s instead of fopen. Is there any solution other than using _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS? I mean, is the fact of filepath input (scanf) compatible with fopen_s? Or just forget it and disable security warnings?

P. S. I know that filepath input *can be unsafe* but I just have to do it this way, because it is stated so in my task.

Comment: Mostly they're safer in the sense they (better) validate their inputs. To use them you don't need to change how file path is entered (so if you used `scanf` you can go on with that or you may switch to its _safe_ version `_cscanf_s`). How to use them? Keep checking return value (in case of `NULL` check `errno`) and be ready to catch (structured) exceptions.

Comment: I may not stated it clear enough. I need to know is it possible to use fopen_s while I have to input the filepath, not to know is it safe enough or not.@gi-joe I checked errno. It's a type for error-handling, how does it help to use an entered file path as a constant string?
@Adriano actually, I'm forced to use scanf_s, I mentioned basic scanf only as an example of what I've been used to. How can I check return value of anything that doesn't even accept arguments that I try to give it? (It doesnt accept char, it asks for const char)

Comment: Yes, you don't need to change how you read path. They both accept `char*` as file path...

Comment: Requiring you to use `fopen_s` is complete Visual Studio stupidity. It's basically identical to `fopen`, it's no more secure at all. It just returns EINVAL if you pass in a NULL pointer rather than segfaulting - but you shouldn't pass in a NULL pointer anyway. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906599/why-cant-i-use-fopen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this makes it safer. This is just good handling of conditions and what you should be doing. Probably should check `errno` too.

That being said, if you have the ability to use `fopen_s`, then I would use it. From MSDN on the "[security enhancements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ef0s5kh.aspx)":

> - Parameter Validation . Parameters passed to CRT functions are
>     validated, in both secure functions and in many preexisting versions
>     of functions. These validations include:
>
>   - Checking for NULL values passed to the functions.
>   - Checking enumerated values for validity.
>   - Checking that integral values are in valid ranges.
>
>   For more information, see Parameter Validation.
> - A handler for invalid parameters is also accessible to the developer. When an encountering an invalid parameter, instead of
>     asserting and exiting the application, the CRT provides a way to check
>     these problems with the _set_invalid_parameter_handler function.
> - Sized Buffers . The secure functions require that the buffer size be passed to any function that writes to a buffer. The secure versions
>     validate that the buffer is large enough before writing to it, helping
>     to avoid dangerous buffer overrun errors that could allow malicious
>     code to execute. These functions usually return an errno type of error
>     code and invoke the invalid parameter handler if the size of the
>     buffer is too small. Functions that read from input buffers, such as
>     gets, have secure versions that require you to specify a maximum size.
> - Null termination . Some functions that left potentially non-terminated strings have secure versions which ensure that strings
>     are properly null terminated.
> - Enhanced error reporting . The secure functions return error codes with more error information than was available with the preexisting
>     functions. The secure functions and many of the preexisting functions
>     now set errno and often return an errno code type as well, to provide
>     better error reporting.
> - Filesystem security . Secure file I/O APIs support secure file access in the default case.
> - Windows security . Secure process APIs enforce security policies and allow ACLs to be specified.
> - Format string syntax checking . Invalid strings are detected, for example, using incorrect type field characters in printf format
>     strings.