# error C4996: 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe

Tags: visual-c++, itk

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and ITK 4.3 for image segmentation but it has an error:

> \itk4.3.1-64bit\debug\include\itk-4.3\gdcmVR.h(168): error C4996:
> 'strerror': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
> strerror_s instead. To disable deprecation, use
> _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

how to overcome this error?

Comment: Is this in building `ITK` or using `ITK` with your application. If it is using `ITK` with your application are you using `CMake` to generate the project file for your application?

Comment: The answer is on http://stackoverflow.com/a/900363/383779

Answer (score 0):

In general you could do the following, but if you are using cmake then you might want to add this option as an additional compiler flag in cmake.

Right click on the project, then navigate to

- `Configuration Properties`
- `C/C++`
- `Command Line`

Down below in the `Additional Options` section you can add:
`-D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`

[image: example]

Additional information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20448102/1460794).

Comment: This may not work well for `ITK` since the project file is generated using `CMake`. Every time a `CMake` generation is triggered all compiler settings that are manually added will be thrown out.

Comment: @drescherjm Good point, I've make a mention of this in the answer.