# std::string constructor with lvalue throws with clang

Tags: c++, clang, lvalue, strerror

I am making use of Matei David's [handy C++ wrapper for zlib](https://github.com/mateidavid/zstr), but I get an error when compiling on macOs (clang-1100.0.33.

```
 include/strict_fstream.hpp:39:37: error: cannot initialize a parameter of type 'const char *' with an lvalue of type 'int'
```

The problem is here:

```
/// Overload of error-reporting function, to enable use with VS.
/// Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/a/901316/717706
static std::string strerror()
{
    std::string buff(80, '\0');

    // options for other environments omitted, where error message is set
    // if not Win32 or _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L, error message is left empty.

    auto p = strerror_r(errno, &buff[0], buff.size());

    // error next line
    std::string tmp(p,  std::strlen(p));
    std::swap(buff, tmp);
    buff.resize(buff.find('\0'));
    return buff;
}
```

(Which IIUC has nothing to do with zlib, just trying to report errors in a thread safe manner).

If I change to this:

```
static std::string strerror()
{
    std::string buff(80, '\0');

    auto p = strerror_r(errno, &buff[0], buff.size());

    // "fix" below
    size_t length = buff.size();
    std::string tmp(p,  length);
    std::swap(buff, tmp);

    buff.resize(buff.find('\0'));
    return buff;
}
```

My program compiles and runs fine.

I have two questions:

1. Why does clang not like the constructor `std::string tmp(p,  std::strlen(p));`?
2. The buffer was declared at the beginning of the function as length 80. Why are we even bothering to look up the length?
3. The answer to 2 may answer this, but is there something wrong with my version?

Thanks.

Comment: Check the documentation for `strerror_r`. There are two completely different versions of it floating around, with different return values. You have the one that returns an `int`. That's what your `strerror_r` obviously returns, and constructing a `std::string` from an int, as the error message clearly complains about, very clearly, is not going to end well.

Comment: There is an ISO C (and ISO C++ by inclusion) function called `strerror`; to avoid confusion it might be good to rename this function something else

Comment: Yes, thanks @M.M, it is actually in a namespace in the original code. Got a little aggressive with my code trimming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `int strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);`, then there is no appropriate string constructor and the program is ill formed.

If you use `char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);`, then the program is well-formed.

The standard C/POSIX library implementation influences which function you get. Compiler is only involved as much as influencing what system library may be used by default.

Former function is extension to POSIX specified in XSI (which is essentially an optional part of POSIX) and latter is a GNU extension.

In case you use glibc (I don't know if that is an option on MacOS), you can control which version you get with macros, although the XSI compliant version is not available in older versions. Its documentation says:

> The XSI-compliant version of strerror_r() is provided if:
>   (_POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 200112L || _XOPEN_SOURCE >= 600) && ! _GNU_SOURCE

---

> 2. The buffer was declared at the beginning of the function as length 80. Why are we even bothering to look up the length?

In the construction `std::string tmp(p,  std::strlen(p));`, `strlen` seems entirely unnecessary to me. `std::string tmp(p);` is equivalent.

---

If you don't need thread safety, then the most portable solution is to use `std::strerror` which is in standard C++:

```
return std::strerror(errno); // yes, it's this simple
```

If you do need thread safety, then you could wrap this in a critical section using a mutex.

---

Note that `strerror`, the name of your function, is reserved to the language implementation in the global namespace when the standard library is used. The function should be in a namespace, or be renamed.

Comment: I guess one could make "portable" code based on overloading or whatever that works for both versions of `p`

Comment: Got it. The original code referenced in my question does have a couple versions, one for POSIX compliant strerror and one for the GCC strerror. It seems I need to tweak the compiler directives to catch the fact that clang wants the POSIX one.

Comment: Or, rather, not that clang wants the POSIX one, but that the version of libc I have is the POSIX compliant one.

Answer (score 2):

There are two different versions of the `strerror_r` that you'll commonly see:

- A POSIX-compliant version that always stores the error message in the provided buffer (if it succeeds) and returns an `int` (`0` for success, non-zero for error)
- A GNU version that *may* store the error message in the provided buffer, or maybe not.  It returns a `char*` pointing to the error message, which may point to the user-supplied buffer or may point to some other global static storage.

That `strerror` function is clearly written to work with the GNU version of `strerror_r`.

---

As for your second question, you need the `strlen`.  `buff` is 80 characters long, but the actual error message may be shorter and only partially fill the buffer.  That `strlen` is being used to trim off any extra nul characters from the end.