# GNU strerror_r buffer meaning

Tags: c, glibc, strerror

```
char *strerror_r(int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen);
```

What are these `buf`/`buflen` parameters for?

#### Empty buffer works like a charm:

```
char* buf = nullptr;
fprintf(stderr, strerror_r(errno, buf, 0));
```

#### Also this buffer looks like unused:

```
char buf[1024];
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror_r(errno, buf, sizeof buf)); // Correct message here
fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", buf); // Empty
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you noticed in comments, **buf** and **buflen** parameters is used only if you pass invalid **errnum**, negative or unknown **errno** value. This is confirmed by [the source code of the function](https://github.com/bminor/glibc/blob/master/string/_strerror.c#L37).

```
char *
__strerror_r (int errnum, char *buf, size_t buflen)
{
  if (__builtin_expect (errnum < 0 || errnum >= _sys_nerr_internal
                        || _sys_errlist_internal[errnum] == NULL, 0))
    {
      /* To fill up buf with "Unknown error" localized string and to append
         digits of errnum. Nothing happens if buflen equals zero. */

      ...

      return buf;
    }

  return (char *) _(_sys_errlist_internal[errnum]);
}
```

In relation capacity of the buffer, I think 1024 bytes will be enough. Moreover, it's the exact same size which **strerror** implementation uses (that's thread unsafe). See also [the related answer and the comment to it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/423301/5000805).

Of course, it all is concern of GNU-version of the function. XSI-compliant version always uses this buffer for copy of a static string.

Comment: Can you point, why 32 bytes is not enough? `"Unknown error %d"` never exceeds it... Oh, key is `localized string`. It can be some longer in other locales. Am I right?

Comment: Yeah. For example, if you set Russian locale, this string will be translated as `"Неизвестная ошибка"`, which occupies 35 bytes in UTF-8 encoding. Also add to it 11 symbols (minimum value of **int** contains at least 10 digits and minus sign, but **__strerror_r** reserves 20 characters for this purpose).

Answer (score 3):

Quoting from the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror_r), *emphasis mine*

> The GNU-specific `strerror_r()` returns a pointer to a string containing the error message. **This may be either a pointer to a string that the function stores in `buf`, or a pointer to some (immutable) static string *(in which case `buf` is unused)*.**

So it is very much possible that `buf` is left unused and in case, `buf` is unused, the `buflen` does not matter.

> [....] **If the function stores a string in `buf`**, then at most `buflen` bytes are stored (the string may be truncated if `buflen` is too small and `errnum` is unknown). [...]

Comment: So, is it used only for `Unknown error errno` messages? And I still can use return value to access it, right?

Comment: It's probably only used if/when needed. The `_r` suffix usually means *reentrant*, so perhaps in the presence of threads it will be used.

Comment: I was mean `buffer memory` by "it used", not `strerror_r`

Comment: presence of threads changes nothing: [cpp.sh](http://cpp.sh/2l7f6). I just what to know: are there any buffer using messages, that longer than `Unknown error %int%`, or I can use, say `char buf[30]` to not truncate anything?